# multiple selection every N lines Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a very large file (~100k lines) and I want to insert a comment every 100 lines, I can write a script to do it, but I wonder if something like this is possible in Sublime (In emacs is pretty straightforward).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about this regex to find 100 lines at a time

```
((.*\n){1,100})
```

and then replace with

```
\1
// this is a comment
```

Is that close enough for whatever it is you are trying to achieve?

Edit: This version of the replacement text suggested as better by @[Maluchi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943138/maluchi)

```
\1\n
// this is a comment\n
```

Comment: that's almost it, it worked adding `\n` at the beggining and the end of the comment, but the idea is right! Please edit your answer, but I'm accepting it! Thanks!

Comment: What's doing exactly the `\1`?

Comment: @jgarces - "\1" is equivalent to "$1". It means paste the first selection group. Selection groups are delimited by "()".